# Store variables to pass securely between views/pages in java

Tags: java

I want to store a variable in one java page/view and then retrieve it in another page/view. So far I have found (on the server side):

To store the variable for later use:

```
public static void setViewDataState(String state) {
    ViewData viewData = new ViewData();

    //getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("viewData", viewData);
    viewData.setState(state);
    System.out.println("state2 = " + state);
}
```

To retrieve the variable:

```
public static String getViewDataState() {
    ViewData viewData = new ViewData();
    System.out.println("state3 = " + viewData.getState());
    return viewData.getState();
}
```

State2 is displaying the correct value and State3 is displaying null. What is the correct way to do this please. I can do this in GWT; however, I am new to java.

This is how I do it in GWT:

```
public ViewData setViewData(String accountId, String accountLevel,
        String ymId, String awId, String adAwardGroup, String adScoutGroup,
        String caId, Integer numberOfGroupsStarted, String groupSection,
        String hikeRecordID, String hikeMealID, String e1ActivityID,
        String penPalID, String groupNAS) {
    ViewData viewData = new ViewData();

    getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("viewData", viewData);
    viewData.setaccountId(accountId);
    viewData.setaccountLevel(accountLevel);
    viewData.setymId(ymId);
    viewData.setawId(awId);
    viewData.setadAwardGroup(adAwardGroup);
    viewData.setadScoutGroup(adScoutGroup);
    viewData.setcaId(caId);
    viewData.setnoGroupsStarted(numberOfGroupsStarted);
    viewData.setsection(groupSection);
    viewData.sethikeRecordID(hikeRecordID);
    viewData.sethikeMealID(hikeMealID);
    viewData.setactivityE1ID(e1ActivityID);
    viewData.setpenPalID(penPalID);
    viewData.setGroupNAS(groupNAS);
    return viewData;
}

public ViewData getViewData() {
    return (ViewData) getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("viewData");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of external storage. Redis is probably the most common way to track things like this, but if you have a database or some other kind of way to store objects you can use that (depending on what you need in terms of performance).

Comment: I have a database; however, in GWT I was just storing it locally. I will place the GWT code in the question as an example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to move:

```
ViewData viewData = new ViewData();
```

for both the store and retrieve to under the class:

```
public class MySQLConnection implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static ViewData viewData = new ViewData();
    //other code including the store and retrieve
}
```